# How to structure chat application using Firebase Realtime Database to incorporate user data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As of right now I am using Firebase Realtime Database to include chat functionality as part of an app I'm working on. The only issue I've seemingly run into is figuring out how to include a user's data (profile, username, birthday, etc.) so that if a user clicks on a chat, they can then seamlessly go to a user's profile page without needing to fetch more data from the backend. Here's the current structure I'm using in Firebase Realtime Database for this:

```
$chats
  $chatId
    id
    users
      0: some user id
      1: some user id
    lastMessage

$userChats
  $userId
    $chatId: true

$users
  $userId
    user info here
```

In my case what I would like to know is if it makes more sense to duplicate all the user data for each user into each chat within the users array or if I should just use the referencing userId and pull that data after in a separate request?

Considering I store my users primarily in a separate PostgreSQL database I wonder if I could do a separate query to that database and not even worry about storing the users in the realtime database as well (considering I have to include aggregate info for each user like counters).

Comment: All sounds like valid options, and the right considerations. What are you looking for in an answer here (noting that what makes sense is typically quite subjective)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was hoping to find a solution that would be easiest to scale. In my opinion, querying for the users from the Postgres database would be easy enough after I get each chat from Firebase, but not sure how that would impact the overall "realtime" feel of the chat. I only feel like including the users in Firebase  makes sense for offline purposes but my app doesn't plan to support that at the moment.

Comment: This question is going to be tough to answer, and it falls outside of what we do here on SO as questions here are coding specific. Present the code, the issue and we'll take a look. You're really asking a design question. To me, I would be storing all my users in Firebase as it's handles auth beautifully. Also, 'pulling data from the backend' is what Firebase does. It's generally a tiny amount of data and would be 'instantaneous' - have you tried it? If not, you should! While denormalizing is normal with NoSQL, it can be overdone and when the dataset it small, there's often no reason to.

Comment: @Jay I guess I'm trying to determine if it's reasonable to include the user data within the chat object or just reference it by its id. In my opinion I'm only hesitant to store a reference as I'd have to make a query for each individual user.

Comment: *I'd have to make a query for each individual user* and.... what's wrong with that? It's common practice. We have no way of knowing what the context is of when/why you need to do functions in your app. For example *if a user clicks on a chat, they can then seamlessly go to a user's profile page* - that's kinda a normal thing to do , right? Why load a bunch of user data if it's not used until a user clicks on it. You probably need the users name (to show on the chat) and then a reference to their user node. But as mentioned, this is a design decision which we cannot answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *always* going to be fetching user data alongside a chat, then you should store them together. No need to make more than one call unnecessarily.

However, if you will ever fetch user data and/or conversations separately, I would recommend storing the user data separately and not within the conversation.

Also, if you really want an "immediate" feel (beyond the already "realtime" database performance), you could also fetch the user data in the background as soon as a particular chat is opened. That way, if the user taps to view a profile, it'll have already been fetched and will give that "instantaneous" experience you are looking for.

Plus, you have to remember that Realtime Database charges on the amount of data being transferred, no matter how many calls it takes (as opposed to Firestore which charges on the number of queries), so storing it separately does not increase billing at all compared to one query, and actually saves money in the cases where you don't need both data sets.